# Directshow YUV Rendering shows only one frame

Tags: render, directshow, yuv

I am developing a H265 directshow decoder that will handle live stream. I am facing issue while rendering the live stream. It only shows one frame on the rendered active window. On the other the function I am using to fill the output buffer is continuously filling the output buffer.
For testing purposes I stored the output buffer in a file and then rendered it using some YUV player and that file dont have that issue. This means that the buffer is getting the frames but then why render show only one. Where can be the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: This lacks detail. Something is wrong with your frame or decoder, not necessarily video frame data itself (pixels). Incorrect media sample parameters, or you are ignoring error event issues by renderer, or you incorrectly handle dynamic format change requests from renderer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How  can e check the error events issued by renderer. Secondly can you provide me the correct parameter required for live stream rendering and the third is what do you mean by dynamic format change request. Sorry if some question seems silly becase I am new to this.

Comment: And one more thing I am not implementing the decoder, decoder is working fine but when I am implementing directshow filter of the decoder.
Now how can I provide the correct media sample parameters that you pointed out in your previous comment.